# Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, routes

Having a huge push back here in a small weekend project.

I am building a simple SPA application using JS, HTML, and TailwindCSS, and currently having a problem, apparently, with routing when running the application.

This is the form under "pages/home.html"

```
<form id="journalForm" action="/" method="post" class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow p-6">
    <ul>
        <input id="locationName" type="text" placeholder="Location name" class="rounded-md bg-gray-100 p-2" />
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <input id="journalNotes" type="text" placeholder="Add your notes here!" class="rounded-md bg-gray-100 p-2" />
    </ul>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button id="addPhoto" class="rounded-md p-2 bg-gray-100 text-black">Add images &#128248;</button>
        <button type="button" id="addEntry" class="rounded-full bg-gray-100 text-black text-sm">+</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my "js/main.js" file:

```
export class JournalEntries {
    constructor() {
        this.entries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('journalEntries')) || [];
        this.bindForm();
        this.renderEntries();
    }

    bindForm() {
        document.getElementById('addEntry').addEventListener('click', () => {
            const locationName = document.getElementById('locationName').value;
            const journalNotes = document.getElementById('journalNotes').value;
            if (!locationName || !journalNotes) {
                alert('Please fill in all fields.');
                return;
            }
            this.add({ locationName, journalNotes });
            document.getElementById('journalForm').reset(); 
        });
    }

    add(entry) {
        this.entries = [entry, ...this.entries];
        this.update();
        this.save();
    }

    save() {
        localStorage.setItem('journalEntries', JSON.stringify(this.entries));
    }

    update() {
        this.renderEntries();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    new JournalEntries();
});
```

And, finally, this is my router, inside "js/router.js":

```
export class Router {
    routes = {};

    add(routeName, page) {
        this.routes[routeName] = page
    }

    route(event) {
        console.log("Route event activated")
        event = event || window.event
        event.preventDefault()

        window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);

        this.handle()
    }

    handle() {
        const { pathname } = window.location
        const route = this.routes[pathname]

        fetch(route)
            .then(data => data.text())
            .then(html => {
                document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = html;
            });

        console.log(route);
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following errors:

1

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at JournalEntries.bindForm (main.js:9:44)
    at new JournalEntries (main.js:4:14)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:37:5)
```

2

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

3

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/home 404 (Not Found)
```

And being very confused. Can someone provide a little guidance?

Thank you!

Tried fixing classes, inserting console.log alerts, and all that.